# Can't create Wi-Fi hotspot while connected with wire on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, ethernet, hot-spot, wired

There are some answers for the previous Ubuntu versions, but I couldn't apply them since the network settings interface has changed.
I can create a wi-fi hotspot while I am not connected with a wire. But when I plug in the ethernet cable, the wi-fi dropdown in the panel shows "Wi-Fi Hardware Disabled" text.
When I go to Wi-Fi settings, the toggle does not work. I click on three dots on top right and click on Create Hotspot, a pop-up screen shows up to set the password for hotspot; after clicking on OK, it disappears and wi-fi hotspot still isn't opened.

**How can I connect to an ethernet cable (wired connected) and open a wi-fi hotspot at the same time?**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue isn't related to Ubuntu. My laptop disables wi-fi when connected to ethernet via wire. This setting can be changed on BIOS.
For exampple in the BIOS of a Toshiba laptop, the setting is under `System Configuration` tab, with the name `Auto Wireless LAN RF Switching`. Disabling this option solves the problem.